# Convert 4 byte HEX to individual bytes

Tags: python, split, hex

In python, I need to take a value from a user and send it over serial. It's up to a 4-byte value, let's say the value is 123456789. I can convert to HEX with no issue which gives me '0x75bcd15' but I need to send it as 4 individual bytes (b'\x07\x5b\xcd\x15').

I have done this with a 2 byte by bit shifting `

```
stake = int(single_game_stake_entry.get())

stakeMSB = (bytes([stake >> 8]))
stakeLSB = (bytes([stake & 0xFF]))`
```

I can not seem to expand on this for 4 bytes if it is even possible this way. I have tried bytes, bytearray but I can not split the values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: solved it by the method below, not sure if its the best way but it works

`meterNumber = bytes([secmeternumber.get()])
meterValue = hex(int(sec_meter_value_entry.get()))
mvSplit = meterValue.split("0x")
raw = mvSplit[1].zfill(8)
mvA = (raw[0:2])
mvB = (raw[2:4])
mvC = (raw[4:6])
mvD = (raw[6:8])

    mvb1 = bytes.fromhex(mvA)
    mvb2 = bytes.fromhex(mvB)
    mvb3 = bytes.fromhex(mvC)
    mvb4 = bytes.fromhex(mvD)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do that is to use the int.to_bytes() method.
You can call the method in two different ways, as you can see bellow.

```
stake = 123456789
print(int.to_bytes(stake, 4, 'big')) # Call the method of the int class
print(stake.to_bytes(4, 'little')) # Call the method directly on the int to convert
```

You must provide the number of bytes of the result and the order of the bytes (little or big).

Comment: Thank you, that's it! I always over complicate things